# Why the security trimming doesn't apply?

Tags: list, 2013, permissions, security, quick-launch

It seems that the security trimming doesn't apply for the Quick Launch in SharePoint 2013.

I've created 2 lists with broken role inheritance and assigned permissions to a different group for each list (one has "Full Control" and the other one has a custom permission level).

Even if the site contents (`_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`) hides the list which is supposed to be hidden for the current user, the Quick Launch doesn't, i.e. both lists appear in the navigation links.

The security is applied when I try to access the secured list's URL, as expected.

Am I supposed to modify any other permissions? Is there any reference to this change compared to SharePoint 2010?

Comment: i had a similar problem 2 weeks ago and solved it by deleting the quicklaunch link and add it again. Maybe this will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify links in navigation section in system settings of the site, and set the target audience to the link if you want it to be hidden when the user doesn't have permissions for that link :)